# Replace operation: is its write stage atomic with regard to its filter stage?

Tags: mongodb, replace, atomic

We're using the `replaceOne` operation on the collection which uses the "filter" clause to check that it's about to update a document with its certain field having some specific value.

All is good but since the documents in the collection are updated by multiple parties working in parallel, I'd like to know whether it is guaranteed that between the time the filter has found a document to be replaced — that is, the filter *has matched,* — and that very document gets replaced, it is impossible for that document to be replaced by a concurrently running operation.  I failed to find any statement on this in the MongoDB docs.

We're using MongoDB 3.6 (please don't ask why) so using transactions is out of the question.

Comment: You can test this right?

Comment: @D.SM, sorry, test what? You mean, write a stress test and see whether it works? Sorry, but it's impossble to prepare a test which exposes a problem in a robust way: all such a test can show is that the problem _is likely_ to not occur _in the test._ But that is not satisfactory when you're perparing for production use.

Comment: If you have some of the documents of  a batch not updated, you know there isn't the atomicity guarantee. The test won't guarantee there *is* atomicity but it will tell you if there isn't.

Comment: Also asked [on the community forum](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/replace-operation-is-its-write-stage-atomic-with-regard-to-its-filter-stage/7973).